# Sourcing sulfur-oxidizing bacteria

Tags: bacteriology, resource-recommendation

For a research project, I need a species of sulfur-oxidizing bacteria but I cannot find a biological company that sells anything like that. I know ATCC sells some species of sulfur-oxidizing bacteria but those are usually too filtered out than I need thus costing more than $400. Can you provide me with any biological company that sells bacterial species under sulfur-oxidizing bacteria? I know I'm not making it very specific but at this point, I'm good with anything you can find. I would prefer green or purple sulfur bacteria, but anything that can use hydrogen sulfide is good for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous collections around the world that supply bacterial species. You've already found the American Type Culture Collection (ATCC). If you are in academia or even sometimes in industry, you can contact authors of papers who have an organism you want, and they will supply a starter culture to you, usually free (for the organism itself), but you will always have to pay shipping (whether from a supplier or a researcher), which will often run into the hundreds of dollars, depending on shipping type. Many species will only be able to be shipped under certain conditions, such as frozen on dry-ice (about -89 C), or frozen as freeze-dried. These types of shipping cost $$$.

In addition to the shipping there will be some legal things to sort out. Typically this is a [Material Transfer Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_transfer_agreement), which is a legally binding document between your organization and the supplier and/or the people the supplier got it from. These often limit what you can do with the organism in question - usually limiting you to research applications only. If you are intending to commercialize you will need to get a commercial agreement signed up! Not doing so opens you and your organization to legal liabilities that will cost a huge amount of money to litigate and usually result in substantial fines.

In Europe there is the [Belgian Coordinated Collection of Microorganisms](https://bccm.belspo.be/), which has a price list [here](https://bccm.belspo.be/pricelists/lmg-pricelist). There is also the [Leibniz-Institut DSMZ-Deutsche Sammlung von Mikroorganismen und Zellkulturen GmbH](https://www.dsmz.de/) (known as the DSMZ) in Germany and the [Culture Collection University of Gothenburg](https://www.ccug.se/) (CCUG) in Sweden. The UK has the [NCTC](https://www.culturecollections.org.uk/products/bacteria-and-mycoplasmas/) (National Collection of Type Cultures) too.

Japan has the  [Japan Collection of Microorganisms](https://jcm.brc.riken.jp/en/) at the RIKEN organization. China has the [Chinese General Microbiological Culture Collection Centre](https://cgmcc.net/english/)

India has the N[CCCC](https://www.ncccc.in/) (National College Culture Collection Centre) in Pune.

In addition there are lots of smaller ones around the world. There is also the [Global Catalogue of Microorganisms](https://gcm.wdcm.org/), which lists 152 current affiliates from all around the world, including those listed above.